# How to load tile levels in AS3 by using Arrays

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, actionscript-2

I have a very complex issue here,any help will be very much appreciated.
To begin,i do all this by using this tutorial:http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2007/05/21/how-to-load-levels-in-a-flash-tile-based-game/
The problem is,the code in the tutorial is in AS2 while we need to convert it to AS3 in order to be able to debug it for AIR.So our main problem here is to execute the methods in AS2,do everything the same ways but in AS3.
What we're trying to do basically,is we're trying to implement a very smart system for building level from the very code by using Arrays(look up in the tutorial).Depending on the integer values in each array you get different types of blocks as well an empty one.
Here is the AS2 code:

```
 level = new Array();
 level[0] = new Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
 level[1] = new Array(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2);
 level[2] = new Array(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3);
 for (y = 0; y <= 2; y++) {
     for (x = 0; x <= 9; x++) {
         place_brick = attachMovie("brick", "brick_" + _root.getNextHighestDepth(),
         _root.getNextHighestDepth(), {
             _x: x * 50,
             _y: y * 15
         });
         place_brick.gotoAndStop(level[y][x]);
     }
 }
```

You see,we have a brick class and different tiles are indexed by different frames.Depending on the int value you have a particular outcome.This doesn't work in AS3.
And here is the AS3 code:

```
var level: Array = new Array();
var max: int = 0;
var min: int = 0;
level[0] = new Array(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
level[1] = new Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1);
level[2] = new Array(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
level[3] = new Array(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
level[4] = new Array(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
level[5] = new Array(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1);
level[6] = new Array(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1);
level[7] = new Array(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1);
level[8] = new Array(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1);
level[9] = new Array(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1);
level[10] = new Array(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
for (y = 0; y <= 10; y++) {
    for (x = 0; x <= 11; x++) {
        if (level[y][x] == 1) {
            var brickik: brick = new brick();
            addChild(brickik);
            max += 80;
            this.brickik.x += max;
        }
        if (level[y][x] == 0) {
            max += 80;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem we're having is about finding a smart way to programm this whole thing the way it's done in AS2.How can we implement this in AS3 so that we can place tiles anywhere we want of any kind by simply using the Arrays.

Comment: ActionScript 2 and 3 have a lot of differences. Is your problem only in the bit of code you showed or do you have more problems? Try removing the `this` from `this.brickik`. That's where I got an error. Apart from that it seems to be working.

Comment: You can also use `goToAndStop` in AS3. As for a smart way to do that, I'd say it would be better if you controlled the level configuration with external files like XML or Json, and not mess with your code every time you need to change some content. You have to learn to separate content from logic.

Comment: btw `this` here is unnecessary. You are already in the same scope as your `brick` instance.

Comment: Also, for your loops use `length`instead of manually using a number... like `for(var i = 0; i < level.length, i++ )`

Comment: Also depending on your class, `y` and `x` are usually already used. For loops it's more common to use i, j, k etc.

Answer (score 0):

In AS3, your for loops should rather look like this

```
for (var y:int = 0; y <= 10; y++) {
for (var x:int = 0; x <= 11; x++) {
```

Also, you don't have to mention 'this' before brickikx etc.

I don't know if that helps